# Min and Max Value in SQL Sever

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to get min  check in and max check out for users for everday. I tried to find out to do it but I failed.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), checktime, 120), 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), checktime, 108) Time, 
       userid, 
       Max(checktime)                      CheckTimeEvent, 
       checktype 
FROM   checkinout, 
       workdateview 
WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), checktime, 120) = workdateview.workdate 
       AND userid = 2 
       AND checktype = 'O' 
GROUP  BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), checktime, 120), 
          CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), checktime, 108), 
          userid, 
          checktype 
UNION 
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), checktime, 120), 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), checktime, 108) Time, 
       userid, 
       Min(checktime)                      CheckTimeEvent, 
       checktype 
FROM   checkinout, 
       workdateview 
WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), checktime, 120) = workdateview.workdate 
       AND userid = 2 
       AND checktype = 'I' 
GROUP  BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), checktime, 120), 
          CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), checktime, 108), 
          userid, 
          checktype
```

Comment: What **datatype** are those columns?!?!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Max(checktime), 120), 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), Max(checktime), 108) Time, 
       userid, 
       Max(checktime)   CheckTimeEvent, 
       checktype 
FROM   checkinout, 
       workdateview 
WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), checktime, 120) = workdateview.workdate 
       AND userid = 2 
       AND checktype = 'O' 
GROUP  BY userid, 
          checktype 
UNION 
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Min(checktime) , 120), 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), Min(checktime) , 108) Time, 
       userid, 
       Min(checktime)                      CheckTimeEvent, 
       checktype 
FROM   checkinout, 
       workdateview 
WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), checktime, 120) = workdateview.workdate 
       AND userid = 2 
       AND checktype = 'I' 
GROUP  BY userid, 
          checktype
```

Try This

Answer (score 0):

you should not group by time since you are trying to find its max/min. just group by date:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), checktime, 120), 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), checktime, 108) Time, 
       userid, 
       Max(checktime)                      CheckTimeEvent, 
       checktype 
FROM   checkinout, 
       workdateview 
WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), checktime, 120) = workdateview.workdate 
       AND userid = 2 
       AND checktype = 'O' 
GROUP  BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), checktime, 120), 
          userid, 
          checktype 
UNION 
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), checktime, 120), 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), checktime, 108) Time, 
       userid, 
       Min(checktime)                      CheckTimeEvent, 
       checktype 
FROM   checkinout, 
       workdateview 
WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), checktime, 120) = workdateview.workdate 
       AND userid = 2 
       AND checktype = 'I' 
GROUP  BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), checktime, 120), 
          userid, 
          checktype
```